# How to create multiple purpose of function with passing generic type

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way how can pass generic type with a function to create multiple purpose function.

Following function for only getting Collection of Event, but I want to add a parameter to change the type of ResponseEntity and  ParameterizedTypeReference according to a parameter for example; `List<Place>`, `List<Page>`, etc.

Maybe the title is not correct, please edit to make it understandable.
Thank you in advance for your support.

```
public List<Event> getEventList(String url) {
    List<Event> result = Collections.emptyList();
    ResponseEntity<List<Event>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Event>>() {
            });
    if (responseEntity.hasBody()) {
        result = responseEntity.getBody();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing about `ParameterizedTypeReference` is that it seems deceptively simple to just make it generic:

```
new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>() {}
```

but this doesn't work correctly: the "actual" `T` is not available at runtime. The type of the list will actually be `List<Object>`.

You have to provide the concrete `ParameterizedTypeReference` as a parameter:

```
public <T> List<T> getEventList(String url, ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>> ptr) {
  List<T> result = Collections.emptyList();
  ResponseEntity<List<T>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, ptr);
  if (responseEntity.hasBody()) {
    result = responseEntity.getBody();
  }

  return result;
}
```

Invoke like:

```
List<Place> places = getEventList(url, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Place>>() {});
List<Page> pages = getEventList(url, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Page>>() {});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using right now your suggestion. Can we not parameter like a "List<Page>.class" , can we ?

Comment: @egemen if such a thing were possible, there would be no need for classes like `ParameterizedTypeReference`.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly:

---

`public <T> List<T> getEventList(String url) {
    List<T> result = Collections.emptyList();
    ResponseEntity<List<T>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>() {
            });
    if (responseEntity.hasBody()) {
        result = responseEntity.getBody();
    }
  return result;
}`

Comment: I can not use the collection of generic type (List<?>).  Because I get a response as List of LinkedHashMap, if I use.